# What are error 2503 and error 2502 in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install mongo db, but when installing compass it's not working properly. I tried to uninstall and reinstall, but when uninstalling it give two errors: error 2503 and error 2502.

I found an answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-codes-2503-2502-while-unistall-or-install-a/6a996faf-7e28-40bd-b5e0-02ab17dfcd88), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix For Windows error 2502, 2503

msiexec /unreg
msiexec /regserver
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
start explorer.exe

I have successfully resolved the problem Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by adding full permission to the windows Temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

The codes 2503 and 2502 are windows installer error codes (See: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-error-messages) for a list of all windows installer error codes & messages); The issue can come up when installing many programs, so googling this issue will likely lead you to general windows tech support.

For me, I believe the issue was with my clock being un-synced as I was previously playing with set-date on PowerShell to change my system clock.

There are many other suggested fixes which often include the following general steps:

- Relaxing file permissions on `C:\Windows\Installer`
- Relaxing file permissions on `C:\Windows\TEMP`
- Unregistering and reregistering the Windows Installer as suggested in @AnilRana's answer using `msiexec /unreg` & `msiexec /regserver`

For more potential solutions, I recommend searching for error 2503 at https://answers.microsoft.com/ and searching through tech support threads to find suggestions.